# Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet for context error in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, requirejs, webstorm, sql.js

I have been trying to use `sql.js` with NodeJs using WebStorm. I configured the NodeJs in WebStorm and tried running this code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Database Test</title>
    <script src="js/require.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sql.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var fs = require('fs');
    var sql = window.SQL;
    var db = new sql.Database();
    sqlstr = "CREATE TABLE hello (a int, b char);";
    sqlstr += "INSERT INTO hello VALUES (0, 'hello');"
    sqlstr += "INSERT INTO hello VALUES (1, 'world');"
    db.run(sqlstr);
    var res = db.exec("SELECT * FROM hello");
    var stmt = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM hello WHERE a=:aval AND b=:bval");
    var result = stmt.getAsObject({':aval' : 1, ':bval' : 'world'});
    console.log(result);
    stmt.bind([0, 'hello']);
    while (stmt.step()) console.log(stmt.get());
    function add(a, b) {return a+b;}
    db.create_function("add_js", add);
    db.run("INSERT INTO hello VALUES (add_js(7, 3), add_js('Hello ', 'world'));");
    stmt.free();
    var binaryArray = db.export();
    var buffer = new Buffer(binaryArray);
    fs.writeFileSync("filename.sqlite", buffer);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but the code gives me an error in the console as

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

How do I resolve that error and run this complete code successfully?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you can't use `fs` on the front end to write files. But you can store variables in local storage on the front end if that is what you are trying to do?

Set the data in localStorage can be done with the command:

```
localStorage.setItem('nameForData', variableNameForData);
```

To retrieve the data when required.

```
var variableNameForData = localStorage.getItem('nameForData')
```

To remove the data from localStorage:

```
localStorage.removeItem('nameForData')
```

[Docs for local storage here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

**edit to answer comment**

`fs` is used to access the file system in node on the local machine the code is running. With the command:

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

You are loading a included module that comes as part of Node.JS

This will not work in the browser for security reasons.

[There are docs here that explain how `fs` works.](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

As I suggested, if you do want to store data on the front end, local storage is one way of doing so.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to store that into var fs, but the error says it hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: Is there any other way I could come over that error Alexi? Because I need to write the data into a database file in the end, for which I need to use fs.writeFileSync().

Comment: If you are trying to store a database that would typically be done from your server.